# adding Nodes in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Why is this code not working? I borrowed it from a course, and later I tried to make another one in C, but then again it shows the same error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

struct Nodo{
    int dato;
    struct Nodo *next;
};

void InsertarLista(Nodo *&lista, int n);


main(){
    struct Nodo *lista=NULL;
    int n;
    int opcion;
    
    do{
    cout<<"Ingrese un numero:";
    cin>>n;
    InsertarLista(lista,n);
    getch();
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"\nDesea agregar otro elemento a la lista?: (1) si (2) no :\n";
    cin>>opcion;
    }while(opcion!=2);


    
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void InsertarLista(Nodo *&lista, int n){
    Nodo *nuevo = new Nodo();
    nuevo->dato=n;
    
    Nodo *aux1=lista;
    Nodo *aux2;
    
    
    while((aux1->dato<(n)) && (aux1!=NULL)){
        aux2=aux1;
        aux1=aux1->next;    
    }
    
    if(lista==aux1){
        lista=nuevo;
    }else{
        aux2->next=nuevo;
    }
    
    nuevo->next=aux1;
    
    cout<<"elemento"<<n<<" agregado a la lista correctamente.\n";
}
```

I have done queues and stacks before, and I just don't understand why this problem is happening only on linked lists.

Below I posted a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: what error are you getting? ... `code not working` is meaningless

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors. Instead post the code/errors as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In addition, in order to know what this says, one would have to transcribe it and then translate it. That's making it harder on potential answerers.

Answer (score 1):

Upon entry into `InsertarLista()`, `lista` is initially `NULL`.  You assign `lista` to `aux1` and then try to access `aux1->dato` BEFORE checking `aux1` for `NULL`.  You are checking for `NULL` afterwards.

Change this:

```
while((aux1->dato<(n)) && (aux1!=NULL)){
```

To this instead:

```
while((aux1!=NULL) && (aux1->dato<n)){
```

The [`&&` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) evaluates its operands from left-to-right, not right-to-left.  Due to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), the right operand will be evaluated *only* if the left operand evaluates as true first.

Comment: THANK U SO MUCH you just saved my life.